# sequelize create or update with association

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

i have a problem for add data on my db with sequelize.

I have 2 tables with association howmany:

```
const Price = sequelize.define('prices', {
      close: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
        open: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        low: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        high: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
      date: {
          type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });

const Crypto = sequelize.define('cryptos', {
      uuid: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV1,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      shortname: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      name: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
        totalsupling:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        imageurl:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        prooftype:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        premined:{
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    });
```

db.cryptos.hasMany(db.price, {foreignKey: 'fk_cryptoid', sourceKey: 'uuid'});
db.price.belongsTo(db.cryptos, {foreignKey: 'fk_cryptoid', targetKey: 'uuid'});

i can add new entries with :

```
Crypto.create({
    shortname: 'ETH',
    name: 'ethereum',
    totalsupling: 200000000,
    rank: 2,
    prices: [
        {
            close: '125',
                    open: '150',
                    high: '190',
                    low: '102'
            date: new Date()
        },
        {
            close: '125',
                    open: '150',
                    high: '190',
                    low: '102'
            date: new Date()
        }
    ]
}, {
    include: [ Price ]
}).then(() => {
    res.send("Done!");
})
```

But i can't add a new entity price with association in Crypto entity already existing :

```
Crypto.findOne({
    where: {uuid: 'f0a7e0e0-793d-11e8-b166-d7ecc2040fbe'},
    include: [ {model: Price }]
}).then(
    function (obj) {
       return obj.Price.updateAttributes(
                {
                    close: '125',
                    open: '150',
                    high: '190',
                    low: '102'
                }
                ).then(() => {
            console.log('done!!')
        })
    });
```

Message error :

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateAttributes' of undefined
at /home/blind/Documents/Init-Site-Info-Crypto/Controller/init.controller.js:65:29
at tryCatcher (/home/blind/Documents/Init-Site-Info-Crypto/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/blind/Documents/Init-Site-Info-Crypto/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (/home/blind/Documents/Init-Site-Info-Crypto/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/blind/Documents/Init-Site-Info-Crypto/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/home/blind/Documents/Init-Site-Info-Crypto/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
at Async._drainQueue (/home/blind/Documents/Init-Site-Info-Crypto/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
at Async._drainQueues (/home/blind/Documents/Init-Site-Info-Crypto/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/blind/Documents/Init-Site-Info-Crypto/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
at runCallback (timers.js:800:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:762:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:733:5)
```

Comment: Is there any output you can show?

Comment: i have edit this post

Answer (score -1):

In you association, the crypto has **many** prices. So, if you include your price model in the crypto, it should return an array of prices, and you can't do an updateAttributes in the array directly. That's one problem. The other problem is that your code could not associate the tables.

Try using an alias for your associations. Something like this:

```
db.cryptos.hasMany(db.price, {as: 'prices', foreignKey: 'fk_cryptoid', sourceKey: 'uuid'}); 
db.price.belongsTo(db.cryptos, {as: 'crypto', foreignKey: 'fk_cryptoid', targetKey: 'uuid'});
```

Then you can access like

```
Crypto.findOne({
    where: {uuid: 'f0a7e0e0-793d-11e8-b166-d7ecc2040fbe'},
    include: [{model: Price, as: 'prices'}]
})
.then(function (prices) {
   console.log(prices)
})
```